# Retrieve data from firebase realtime database and auto fill into textbox

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the data from firebase real time database, and auto fill it up with the data inside the database which the user had already key in once they sign up. I saved the user data under their UID , now I have a problem for retrieving the data from the database by their UID and auto fill for the user by current login user uid.

My Firebase database
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLz4q.jpg

The places to be auto-filled
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BA8V.jpg

I tried all possible solutions for my code, but i cant seem to make it work, all solutions i found on stackoverflow, but still it doesnt work for me.

**My JS file**

```
 firebase.database().ref('Users/User Information').child(uid).once('value', 
 function(snapshot) {

   document.getElementById('name').value = snapshot.child("Name").val();
 });
```

**My HTML file**

```
 <td>Name:</td>
 <td>
     <input type="text" id="name" name="name" style="font-size:10pt; width:200px;" placeholder="Enter Name Here" required>
 </td>
```

Now I want to fill the data for the current logged in user automatically based on their UID.

Comment: `console.log(snapshot.child("Name").val());` what it prints?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "[object HTMLInputElement]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
    at Jr (firebase.js:1)
    at e.child (firebase.js:1)
    at svcschedule.js:76

but if i delete the .child(uid) it prints null

Comment: Your ref path has a space. Have you tried changing the ref path?

Comment: Zunnurain, i checked my ref path, it does not have space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users/User Information/'+uid.value).once('value', 
 function(snapshot) {
   document.getElementById('name').value = snapshot.val().Name;
});
```

Or this with arrow function:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users/User Information/'+uid.value).once('value', (snapshot) => 
{
  document.getElementById('name').value = snapshot.val().Name;
});
```

Comment: The code works without the .child(uid), but it prints "undefined" in the text box. It doesnt work when i have the .child(uid)

Comment: It still doesnt work, i think there is something wrong with my auth code

Comment: Alright, i found out the problem, i think firebase is not getting my response correctly, i tried to delete the .child(uid) , and i change my path of ref to my database path which is, .ref('Users/User Information/<my uid>') , then it returns the value correctly, but this is static code for User A, which means if i login to User B, it still show the values of User A but User B is actually the one login. Can you provide on how to solve this?

here is the code demo, https://jsfiddle.net/jyeeyap/fwz7L0g6/

Comment: can it be somewhat related to my database rules? This is the rules i have now
<code>
         {
       "rules": {
        ".read": true,
         ".write": true
      }

       } </code>

Comment: Still no luck... i am still gettting this error.

Uncaught Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "Users/User Information/[object HTMLInputElement]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: You are passing HTML element instead You need to pass value of that HTML input

Comment: "ref('Users/User Information/'+uid) " when i use this code, it show me that error of Uncaught Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "Users/User Information/[object HTMLInputElement]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]", but when is use this ref('Users/User Information/'), it does not show any error. I cannot see any log because the code is not run i think. Sorry to trouble you, i am a beginner , still learning firebase...

Comment: @jyeeyap what is the value for `console.log(uid)`?

Comment: Dear Prashant, the updated answer seems to be working, but i now have a new problem, the value return to be undefined.

Comment: what is the value for -> `snapshot.val()`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: snapshot is not defined

Comment: Can you check on my demo code, https://jsfiddle.net/jyeeyap/fwz7L0g6/ , and see if there is any mistake on the code..

Comment: The previous code with the link, i have change the REF path to directly access the UID data, you can try this demo here, https://jsfiddle.net/jyeeyap/fwz7L0g6/10/  . it does not work.. it shows value as undefined

Comment: use uId is not retrieving that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I done this by using document.getelementbyID , and link it to the child of the database.